# changing label on linkbutton click inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using an asp.net repeater in my asp.net page like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="lblsSICCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sSICCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("sSICCode") %>' OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="MyUpdate">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sSICCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to change the label text whenever a linkbutton is clicked. I am using following code but it changes labels of all repeater. Label1 in front of selected row should get value of mylabel.

```
 Protected Sub LinkButton1_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "MyUpdate" Then
        For Each RI As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
            Dim MyLabel As Label = TryCast(RI.FindControl("lblsSICCode"), Label)

            If MyLabel IsNot Nothing Then

                If MyLabel.Text = e.CommandArgument Then
                    Response.Write(e.CommandArgument + "<br />")
                End If

            End If
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't actually limiting the loop to just the particular item you care about; it's executing the contents for everything. You need to check if the particular item you want is the right index / contains the right element, etc for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a command argument inside LinkButton1 with the index of the repeater item. Next find the Label control as you did in the right repeater item.

EDIT: Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName.Equals("MyUpdate") Then
        Dim MyLabel As Label = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblsSICCode"), Label)
        Dim Label1 As Label = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("Label1"), Label)

        If MyLabel IsNot Nothing Then
            Label1.Text = MyLabel.Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The above event handler will fire if you leave the CommandName in the Linkbutton inside the repeater.

Comment: Please have a look at updated question. I want label1 to be populated with mylaebl value on select click

Comment: See updated post. Instead of creating an event handler for the linkbutton, make one for the repeater. The ItemCommand will fire if you click on the Linkbutton. Make sure the CommandName="MyUpdate" remains inside the Linkbutton tag. This code is also more performant, as you do not need to loop through all repeater items.